# Android DroidCharts SaveInstanceState Issue?

Tags: android, charts, parcelable, savestate, android-lifecycle

I am using JFreeChart ( http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/ ) as a charting library. But for Android I use DroidCharts ( http://code.google.com/p/droidcharts/) which is basically JFreechart for Android. I have created a chart on android. Initially it is clear, then I can add some values to plot and it plots on the chart.

When I rotate my android orientation from portrait to landscape, the screen is blank once again due to the android lifecycle (it goes on to destroy and onCreate is called once again).

I need to know how can I save my plot points using "onSaveInstanceState" to create once again on "onRestoreInstanceState" when the orientation is changed. ? Any code snippet would be helpful . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html) suggests:you have to save values in  object